# Axios - get url with parameters without actually making request

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a bit of code in my React project that looks like this:

```
        const url = '/create-label-shipments.json';
        const filters = Object.assign({}, this.state.filters);
        filters.page = this.state.page;
        const response = await axios.get(url, {params: filters});
```

Now I know that axios takes that `params` object and creates a new url with query parameters, like `'/create-label-shipments.json?page=1&date=2020-03-20&etc...'`

What I am hoping I can do is call some axios function in a different part of my code that does exactly like above, but instead of making the request and giving me the response, it just gives me the URL.

```
        const url = '/create-label-shipments.csv';
        const filters = Object.assign({}, this.state.filters);
        const url = await axios.getUrl(url, {params: filters});
        // at this point, no request was made, and url === '/create-label-shipments.csv?page=1&date=2020-03-20&etc...'
```

Comment: You can create your own custom function to do this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps you're after `axios#getUri()`, which you could use by adding the `params` property and the `url` property to the config object passed to the method:

```js
const params = {
  page: 1,
  date: '2020-03-20'
}

const url = '/create-label-shipments.csv';
const res = axios.getUri({url, params});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha256-T/f7Sju1ZfNNfBh7skWn0idlCBcI3RwdLSS4/I7NQKQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```